# .net standard- how to use flurl with polly

Tags: .net, polly, circuit-breaker, flurl

In .net standard if Polly can be used with flurl?

I'm trying to use Polly circuit breaker in .net standard project with flurl.
I see in .net core ther is a way to use it. But with .net standard I'm not able to open circuit when exceptions are there.

Comment: Could you please share with us the working .Net Core code? Could you also elaborate on what do you mean by *with .net standard I'm not able to open circuit when exceptions are there*?

Comment: The project is of .net standard (project B).
The NuGet of the project B is planned to consume in .net framework web Api project (project A). Project A has the controller but the http call is to dependent service happens in project B. 
I want to implement Polly circuit breaker with Flurl call in project B. Due to some constraint it is ruled out to implement circuit breaker in project A.

Comment: I'm confused. In the question you are saying that you can't use CB in .NET standard project (B). In the comment you have stated that CB is ruled out in project A. Please amend your question to include all the necessary information to be able to reproduce the problem on any machine. Without that we are not able to help you.

Comment: @PeterCsala Sorry for not being clear. The project is of .net standard (project B). The NuGet of the project B is planned to consume in .net framework web Api project (project A). Project A has the controller but the http call is to dependent service happens in project B. I want to implement Polly circuit breaker with Flurl call in project B. 
 Due to some constraint it is ruled out to _define circuit Polly breaker policy in project A_.
I've to define policy and associate it in project B only.